# Change tooltips title at chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

i would like to assign a different title to tooltips for my chart (created with chart js 2.9.2) Therefore I have created an array which should always be displayed accordingly. Unfortunately it does not work as I hoped it would. I hope someone can help me with this problem.

My array looks like this:

```
var new_title = [<?php echo "'".$title_new."'";?>];
```

And my attempt looks like this:

```
title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
    for (var x = 0; x < tooltipItems.length; x++) {
    return new_title[x];    
    };
},
```

Thanks in advance and apologies for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to update the `title` callback like:

```
title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
    return new_title[tooltipItem[0].index]; 
},
```

DEMO:

```js
const new_title = ['This is a custom title'];
new Chart($("#barchart"), {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    "labels": ["Label"],
    "datasets": [{"data": [40]}]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          return new_title[tooltipItem[0]['index']];
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.js"></script>

<canvas id="barchart" width="80" height="20"></canvas>
```